# How do I draw more than one item onto a canvas at a time?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm trying to create multiple circles (food for a game) spawned randomly throughout a canvas.

```html
<html>
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 <head>
  <title>Circle</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <canvas id="circ"></canvas>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var circ=document.getElementById("circ");
  var ctx=circ.getContext("2d");
  var colors=["blue", "red", "green", "purple", "pink", "yellow"]; //colors to use for the food
  
     foodPosX=(Math.random()*300); //getting a random x coord
     foodPosY=(Math.random()*150); //get a random y coord

  for (food=0; food<10; food++) { // if food is less than 10 then add more food
      ctx.arc(foodPosX, foodPosY, randInt(3,6), 0, 2*Math.PI); //drawing a circle for the food
            ctx.fillStyle= colors[randInt(0,7)]; // choose random color from var colors
            ctx.fill(); //fill the circle with the color
  }

  function randInt(min, max) { //gets a random integer between whatever values you need
      min=Math.ceil(min);
      max=Math.floor(max);
      return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min))+min;
  }

 </script>
 <style>
  #circ {
   border: 1px solid black;
  }
 </style>
</body>
</html>
```

I've been trying to find a solution for a while now and can't seem to figure it out. I tried getImageData but I'm not sure on how to use it for my specific situation. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you currently are doing is drawing 10 circles at the same position since your `foodPosX` and `foodPosY` is only set once.

Move `foodPosX=(Math.random()*300);` (and `foodPosY`) inside the `for` loop.
You'll also need to add `ctx.beginPath();` otherwise you'll draw "arcs" between the circles and that'll look weird.

```html
<html>
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 <head>
  <title>Circle</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <canvas id="circ"></canvas>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var circ=document.getElementById("circ");
  var ctx=circ.getContext("2d");
  var colors=["blue", "red", "green", "purple", "pink", "yellow"]; //colors to use for the food

  for (food=0; food<10; food++) { // if food is less than 10 then add more food
      foodPosX = Math.random()*300; //getting a random x coord
      foodPosY = Math.random()*150; //get a random y coord
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(foodPosX, foodPosY, randInt(3,6), 0, 2*Math.PI); //drawing a circle for the food
      ctx.fillStyle = colors[randInt(0,7)]; // choose random color from var colors
      ctx.fill(); //fill the circle with the color
  }

  function randInt(min, max) { //gets a random integer between whatever values you need
    min=Math.ceil(min);
    max=Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min))+min;
  }

 </script>
 <style>
  #circ {
   border: 1px solid black;
  }
 </style>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That explains why sometimes it would look like it had a border of one of the colors. Thanks for the help.